# Calling localhost on a multidomain nginx server

Tags: php, http, curl, nginx, localhost

I'm using nginx to run multiple (sub)domains on one server. One of them is `domain.com`, another `api.domain.com`. I want to use server-side calls to the API from the main domain.

If I'd do an HTTP request from `domain.com` to `api.domain.com`, would the data get out of the server, or would the server recognize it's him being requested, and immediately  serve the request? I ask that, because the second may be faster.

If it does not recognize it, I would like to do a request to localhost. However, when I call localhost, the nginx server wouldn't know what domain to serve. Is there a way to tell nginx how to treat a request for localhost, by passing a requested host parameter, so that the server knows he has to server `api.domain.com` and not an other domain on the server? If it's of any importance, I'm using cURL - but I'm free to use anything else as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to add a line to the file : **/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1 api.domain.com
```

After saving the file if you run a ping on your server it should return something like :

```
user@domain:~$ ping api.domain.com
PING api.domain.com (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.026 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.030 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.031 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=4 ttl=64 time=0.029 ms
```

The file /etc/hosts will have higher priority than your machine DNS server to resolve the name.

If everything is configured properly your cURL should now use localhost to retrieve page from api.domain.com pages. You can verify it by running curl with verbose option :

```
user@domain:~$ curl --verbose api.domain.com
* About to connect() to api.domain.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
```

The first lines will let you know if you are indeed using localhost ip for the request !

---

*In the very unlikely case it does not, check the file : **/etc/nsswitch.conf** and verify the hosts line look like this (files have priority over dns server) :*

```
hosts: files dns
```